# Browser is "Connecting" to site on each page change

Tags: performance, apache, networking, google-chrome-devtools, varnish

In Chrome dev tools, on Network tab, loading HTML page of normal website (e.g. StackOverflow) at first time looks like this:

[image]

... if I continue browsing this website, the "Connecting" time is not present anymore, and request to HTML file looks like this:

[image]

But on a website that I'm working on, the "Connecting" time is present on **each page load**:

[image]

In [Chrome dev tools documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network?hl=ru) "Connecting" status is explained as: "Time it took to establish a connection, including TCP handshakes/retries, DNS lookup, and time connecting to a proxy or negotiating a secure-socket layer (SSL)."

I'm using apache and sending request to simple static file. Do you know what can cause this and what might be wrong in config of server?

Comment: Keepalive is not happening? Examine the traffic with Wireshark to see if the server is closing the connection every time.

Comment: @JimGarrison, thank you very much, your reply sent me in right direction and I've figured it out. I was using Varnish and it has an option sess_timeout, which (I guess) is timeout when sessions will be closed. By default it's set to 5 seconds. Do you think that I might get any problems if I increase it to ,for example, 30 sec?