# Why Varnish sess_timeout is so low by default?

Tags: apache, networking, varnish

Varnish has parameter `sess_timeout`([docs here](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/varnishd.html)), by default it is set to 5 seconds. Which means that after 5 seconds the session will be closed, and next page load will require will require extra 100ms (in average) to connect to server (I've described this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172627/browser-is-connecting-to-site-on-each-page-change?noredirect=1#comment35438482_23172627)).

- Why this parameter is so low by default?
- If I increase it to 60 seconds, will it cause any problems on the server?
- Does it matter what do I use behind the Varnish - nginx or apache? Or varnish optimizes the connections by itself?
- What's the recommended value for average website (e.g. Magento store with 500 active users at a time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sess_timeout is tuned to avoid keeping state around when it is not needed. Worker threads are (in high traffic situations) a precious resource, and having one waiting around doing nothing isn't productive.

For all HTTP clients I know, manual netcat/telnet excluded, it does not take 5s to push through the 100-150 byte long HTTP request.

You can safely increase this to 60s if you feel you need to. If you are using this for long-running connections, you should probably use return(pipe) instead; different timers apply there.